# I want to share youtube link in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

if i want to post video url then what should to write controller code... please give me any suggetion..
Here is my controller where i post a image with status

My controller:

```
 public function getclass(Request $request)
{
    if(Input::has('post_comment'))
    {
        $status=Input::get('post_comment');
        $commentBox=Input::get('comment_text');
        $selectedStatus=Status::find($status);

        $selectedStatus->comments()->create([
           'comment_text'=>$commentBox,
           'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
           'status_id'=>$status

            ]);
        Flash::message('Your comments has been posted');
        return redirect(route('class'));
    }

    if(Input::has('status-text'))
    {
        $text=e(Input::get('status-text'));
        $rules = [
             'status_text'=>'required|string',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if(Input::hasFile('status_image_upload'))
        {
            $rules['status_image_upload'] = 'image';
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if($validator->fails())
            {
                $image = $request->file('status_image_upload');

                $imageName = str_random(8).'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
                //$imageFull = str_random(8).'_'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

                $image->move('status_images', $imageName);

                $userStatus = new Status();
                $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
                $userStatus -> image_url = $imageName;
                $userStatus -> type = 1;
                $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $userStatus -> save();

                Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                return redirect(route('class'));
            }else{
                return back()->with('error','Validation failed:'. $validator->errors);
            }
        }else{
         if($validator->fails())
            {
                $userStatus = new Status();
                $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
                $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $userStatus -> save();

                Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                return redirect(route('class'));
            }else{
                return back()->with('error','Validation failed:'. $validator->errors);
        }
    }
    }

    return view('class',[
        'top_15_posts'=>status::orderBy('id','DESC')->take(15)->get()
        ]);
}
```

Here is my view page where show image/status

My View:

```
<p> {{ $status->status_text }} </p>   
     @if($status->type == 1)
      <a href="{{ $status->image_url }}"></a>
         <img src="{{asset('status_images/'.$status->image_url)}}" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;">
     @endif
```

this is my database table
My Database

```
 $t->increments('id')->unique();
        $t->longtext('status_text');
        $t->integer('users_id')->unsigned();
        $t->longtext('image_url');
        $t->longtext('video_url');
        $t->integer('type');
        $t->timestamps();
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where the URL is comming from? put where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It should be like this:

```
public function getclass(Request $request)
{
    if (Input::has('post_comment'))
    {
        $status=Input::get('post_comment');
        $commentBox=Input::get('comment_text');
        $selectedStatus=Status::find($status);

        $selectedStatus->comments()->create([
        'comment_text'=>$commentBox,
        'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
        'status_id'=>$status
        ]);
        Flash::message('Your comments has been posted');
        return redirect(route('class'));
    }
    if(Input::has('status-text'))
    {
        $text=e(Input::get('status-text'));
        $rules = [
        'status_text'=>'required|string',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);


        if(Input::hasFile('status_image_upload'))
        {
            $rules['status_image_upload'] = 'image';
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if($validator->fails())
            {
                $image = $request->file('status_image_upload');
                $imageName = str_random(8).'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move('status_images', $imageName);
                $userStatus = new Status();
                $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
                $userStatus -> image_url = $imageName;
                $userStatus -> type = 1;
                $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $userStatus -> save();
                Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                return redirect(route('class'));
            }
        }
        else if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $userStatus = new Status();
            $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
            $userStatus -> video_url = $request['video_url'];
            $userStatus -> type = 2;
            $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $userStatus -> save();
            Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
            return redirect(route('class'));
        }
}


return view('class',[
'posts'=>status::orderBy('id','DESC')->get()
]);}
```